# S3: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, bucket

After configure AWSCLI using command `aws configure` . I'm trying to download files from S3 bucket to local folder test, using following command

```
aws s3 sync s3://sourceBucket  ./test --delete
```

but it's throwing following error message

```
download failed: s3://sourceBucket/jobs/Test/1/slider-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to test/jobs/Test/1/slider-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
download failed: s3://sourceBucket/jobs/Test/2/slider-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to test/jobs/Test/2/slider-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

sourceBucket had following permissions

[sourceBucket permissions Image - clickhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvfby.png)

When I check List of objects in sourceBucket using this command

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket sourceBucket --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key, Size: Size}'
```

following is the output of it

```
[
    {
        "Key": "jobs/Test/1/slider-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war", 
        "Size": 2546325
    },
    {
        "Key": "jobs/Test/2/slider-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war", 
        "Size": 3571598
    }
]
```

could some one let me know how to solve this, I need to download the all objects from s3 sourceBucket to local folder test.

Thank you.

Comment: You also have a bucket policy.  Any applicable `deny` in there would override the checkboxes.

Comment: it has no bucket policy.

Comment: Click "edit bucket policy" to be certain?

Comment: I didn't add any policy to bucket, incase if i've to add could you tell me what policy to add, so that it can retrieve all the data from sourceBucket to local folder test.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html

Comment: `{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy1357935677554",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt135793564721",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sourceBucket"
  }
 ]
}`

I used this policy earlier, still showing the same error.

Comment: You don't have the permissions to do it. If you are using IAM role (if you are running this command in an EC2 instance) or an IAM User (if you are running this command in your laptop), enable the following policy:
`s3:GetObject`. Once updated, give it a few seconds and try again. The resource should be your bucket (for added security).

The problem here is not the bucket policy but your IAM permissions because you are using aws cli.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 18):

If you use KMS to encrypt your S3 files, also make sure the IAM user / role has access to use the appropriate key to decrypt the file. In your [KMS dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/kms), click on 'Customer Managed Keys' then click on the specific key used for the S3 bucket. You'll then need to add the appropriate accounts / roles to the key policy. For more see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam

Comment: Your answer helped a lot! I was stuck looking at S3 permission and forgot to check kms permissions.

Comment: Yep this is what got me -- going to use AWS managed KMS keys in the future.

Comment: Can't find 'Encryption Keys' in the IAM dashboard

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran They moved this option to the KMS console. https://console.aws.amazon.com/kms/ From there you can view your 'customer managed keys' and then update 'key users' as appropriate.